# Dynamic html-select option dropdown of State and County - Can't get County list in dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, html-select

I have read through numerous questions posted in this topic and can't clearly see where I am going wrong in my code. I get the States to list in my html-select option dropdown code without issue. I am following some code I found using AJAX and I really thought I was making progress. All I am trying to do is onChange of the State value, the next html-select would list only the counties in that state. I think the issue is passing the state_id to the mySQL SELECT statement for the Counties. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$sqlState = "SELECT * FROM wp_states ORDER BY state_name";
$resultS = mysqli_query($link,$sqlState);

$sqlCounty = "SELECT * FROM wp_counties WHERE state_id = $_POST[stateId] ORDER BY county_name";
$resultC = mysqli_query($link, $sqlCounty);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#formState { width: 35%;}
#formCounty { width: 35%;}  
</style>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>

<body>
<h6>Please select the State and County you would like to play in:</h6>
<form method='POST'>
    <p>Select State
    <select name="formState" id="formState" required>
        <option value="">Type the name of the State you are in</option>
        <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultS)):;?>
        <option value=<?php echo $row1['id'];?>><?php echo $row1['state_name'];?></option>
        <?php endwhile;?>
    </select></p>
    <div id="County">
    <p>Select County
    <select name="formCounty" id="formCounty" required>
        <option value="">Type the name of the County you are in</option>
        <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultC)):;?>
        <option value=<?php echo $row1['id'];?>><?php echo $row1['county_name'];?></option>
        <?php endwhile;?>
    </select></p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Select" Style = "color:white; background-color:blue" required>        
</form> 

</body>
</html>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#formState').change(function(){
        var state_id = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url:"",
            method:"POST",
            data:{stateId:state_id},
            dataType:"text",
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#formCounty').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

I am hoping my error is in this line of code where I attempt to pass the state_id from the AJAX function to the SELECT statement in this line of code:

```
$sqlCounty = "SELECT * FROM wp_counties WHERE state_id = $_POST[stateId] ORDER BY county_name";
$resultC = mysqli_query($link, $sqlCounty);
```

Here is the new code. I need assistance with adding the variable from the function in the SELECT statement.

```
<script>    
function changeState(s1,s2){
    var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
    var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
    $sqlCounties= "SELECT * FROM wp_counties WHERE state_id =" + s1.value + "ORDER BY county_name ASC";
    $resultC = mysqli_query($_SESSION["link"], $sqlStates);
    return $resultC;
}

</script>   
<body>
<h6>Please select the State:</h6>
<form method='POST'>
    <p>Select State
    <select name="formState" id="formState" onchange="changeState(this.id,'formCounty')" required>
        <option value="">Type the name of the State you are in</option>
        <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultS)):;?>
        <option value=<?php echo $row1['id'];?>><?php echo $row1['state_name'];?></option>
        <?php endwhile;?>
    </select></p>
    <div id="County">
    <p>Select County
    <select name="formCounty" id="formCounty" required>
        <option value="">Type the name of the County you are in</option>
        <?php 
        $resultC = changeCounty();
        while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultC)):;?>
        <option value=<?php echo $row1['id'];?>><?php echo $row1['county_name'];?></option>
        <?php endwhile;?>
    </select></p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Select" Style = "color:white; background-color:blue" required>        
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is in the url ajax is calling?

Comment: And what exactly is the problem? Do you see errors or simply no results? Or maybe wrong results?

Comment: No results for the County Select dropdown. the AJAX Url is the page the code is written on.

Comment: That can't work. You're basically trying to add the whole page into the select. Extract the part that gets counties into a new script and return the needed html from it.

Comment: I have modified the code and got the initial part to work.

Comment: You're mixing PHP and Javascript inside the `script` tag.

Comment: I see that.. thank you..  I am still lost at how I can take the value from the first HTML-Select option and use it in a Select statement for the second html-select option.